# SSRS Format Field with Expression Based on Count of Decimal Places

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have a field in an SSRS report that occasionally contains decimal places. The majority of the time I want to format the field with an "n0" so that I get the nice comma every three digits but no decimal places. However, in the rare cases where there are decimals, I want to format the field "n4". How do I write a expression to detect whether decimals exists?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a way by placing the following expression in the Format property:

```
=iif(Int(Fields!QTY.Value) = Fields!QTY.Value, "N0", "N4")
```

(Note: I found a MSDN page with a different solution to the same type of problem. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/cb81d817-9840-4b4f-9639-1acd48963ff6/how-do-i-format-decimal-places-to-0-or-2-decimal-places). That solution formatted the value directly:

```
=Replace(Round(Fields!QTY.Value,2),".00","")
```

It works great for a wide variety of problems. However, for my purposes I went with the format expression because I wanted the rest of the formatting that the N0 and N4 provide.)

Comment: If you want to format the fields individually, you can use **=FORMATNUMBER(Fields!QTY.Value, IIF(Int(Fields!QTY.Value) = Fields!QTY.Value, 0, 4)**